# Approximation of inverse function

Tags: calculus, limits, approximation

Let $f\left(x\right)=c\log x+x$, I am looking at the following limit: $$\lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{y-f^{-1}\left(y\right)}{\log y}=?$$
Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $(f^{-1})^{'}(y) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}$ along with L'Hospital's Rule, you should get that the limit is $c$.

Comment: You also can use substitute $x=f^{-1}(y)$ and then $y=f(x)$.